# RFC5766-turn-server with TLS

Tags: ssl, webrtc, turn, rfc5766turnserver

I'm trying to start my TURN server with TLS enabled. I use the following line to start the server:

```
daemon --user=$USER $TURN $OPTIONS --tls-listening-port 3478 --cert /root/cert_2014_11/my_domain_nl.crt --pkey /root/cert_2014_11/my_domain_nl.key --CA-file /root/cert_2014_11/PositiveSSLCA2.crt
```

The environment variables in there are set in the config file. The server works fine without TLS using the same startup line, but if I add the three SSL related arguments, the server still isn't reachable over TLS. I tried setting a different port for SLL instead of the standard port, but it still didn't work. Whatever I do, I can reach the server without SLL, but over TLS I can't reach it. The certificate chain I use if fine, I use it for our website as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this exact problem before. Have a look at the documentation for the --CA-file argument:

```
--CA-file <filename>    CA file in OpenSSL format.
                        Forces TURN server to verify the client SSL certificates.
                        By default, no CA is set and no client certificate check is performed.
```

This argument is needed only when you will be verifying *client* certificates. It's not for the certificate chain for your server certificate.

Drop the --CA-file argument, keeping the --cert and --pkey arguments.

EDIT: FYI, the certificate file you give to the --cert option can contain the entire certificate chain (yours and your CA's).